# I cant see the device on android studio

Tags: emulation, android-studio-2.2

I need some help in displaying the actual device in Android Studio. At the moment I can only see the screen of the device but not the rest of the device.

I have attached an image so you can see what I mean.

[image]

Comment: What part of the rest of the device do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

It is not emulator it is design view for layout

Comment: ok so how can I see this with a device I select as it shows on Android studio website.